# How to print multi-dimensional hash in different format

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a hash as follows:

```
h={1=>{'a'=>3,'b'=>2,'c'=>3},2=>{'a'=>2,'b'=>1,'c'=>3},3=>{'a'=>2,'b'=>1,'c'=>3}}
```

I want to print it as follows:

```
inner key  outer key  values
'a'           1           3
'a'           2           2
'a'           3           2
```

Same for `b` and `c`. Please guide me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
puts "inner key  outer key  values"
h.flat_map{|o, h| h.map{|i, v| [i, o, v]}}.sort
.each{|i, o, v| puts "'#{i}'           #{o}           #{v}"}
```

Comment: @SwapnilSawant : You can accept this answer as answered.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily print the table using the following hash:

```
h.flat_map { |k,v| [k].product(v.to_a) }.
  each_with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k]={} }) { |(out,(k,v)),g|
    g[k].update(out=>v) }
  #=> { 'a'=>{ 1=>3, 2=>2, 3=>2 },
  #     'b'=>{ 1=>2, 2=>1, 3=>1 },
  #     'c'=>{ 1=>3, 2=>3, 3=>3 } }
```